# How to track map zoom in react leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

On the page on the left side I have a map and on the right side I have a list of places. Markers for the map and a list of places comes to me from the database.
I need to track the map zoom to filter the list of places and remove those places whose markers are not visible. How can i do this? How can I track the map zoom and implement such logic?

```js
const Map = ({ onSelect }) => {
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "map-markers"));
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      setCoordinates(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <MapContainer
        center={center}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        style={{ height: "100vh" }}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        {coordinates.map((coord, index) => (
          <Marker
            key={index}
            eventHandlers={{
              click: () => {
                onSelect(index);
              },
            }}
            position={[parseFloat(coord.data.lat), parseFloat(coord.data.lon)]}
            icon={defaultIcon}
          />
        ))}
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
const List = ({ selectedHouse }) => {
  const [houseTitles, setHouseTitle] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "map-markers"));
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      setHouseTitle(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "50%" }}>
      {houseTitles.map((title, index) => (
          <ListItem key={index} title={title.data.title} />
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your components are structured as follows:

```
<Parent>
  <List />
  <Map />
</Parent>
```

you could lift the state up into the `Parent` component (so `Parent` is responsible for fetching the data and storing it in React's `useState`). You would need to define 2 states: `allHouses` (the complete list of houses) and `visibleHouses` (the houses in view based on the map bounds):

```
const [allHouses, setAllHouses] = useState([
  {
    id: 1,
    data: {
      title: 'House 1',
      lat: 52.074,
      lon: 5.217,
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    data: {
      title: 'House 2',
      lat: 52.07222,
      lon: 5.221965,
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    data: {
      title: 'House 3',
      lat: 52.07,
      lon: 5.215,
    },
  },
]);

const [visibleHouses, setVisibleHouses] = useState(allHouses);
```

For simplicity, I've hardcoded the data rather than fetching it from an API.

The state can then be passed down to the `List` and `Map` components:

```
<List visibleHouses={visibleHouses} />
<Map
  ...
  allHouses={allHouses}
  setVisibleHouses={setVisibleHouses}
/>
```

Only the `visibleHouses` need to be passed to the `List` component as we only want to display a list of the ones visible based on the map bounds. We'll need to pass `allHouses` along with the `setVisibleHouses` state setter to the `Map` component so that we can render all the houses on the map, and update the list of visible houses as the user moves or zooms the map.

You can use [events](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-events/) to listen for either a map move (`dragend`) or a zoom event (`zoomend`) and then update the `visibleHouses` based on whether each house is in the current [bounds](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-contains) of the `map`:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const map = useMapEvents({
    dragend: () => {
      console.log('moved');

      setVisibleHouses(
        allHouses.filter((c) =>
          map.getBounds().contains({ lat: c.data.lat, lng: c.data.lon })
        )
      );
    },
    zoomend: () => {
      console.log('zoomed');

      setVisibleHouses(
        allHouses.filter((c) =>
          map.getBounds().contains({ lat: c.data.lat, lng: c.data.lon })
        )
      );
    },
  });
  return null;
}
```

Because the `List` component renders the `visibleHouses`, whenever this state is updated as the result of a map move or zoom, it will cause the list to be updated accordingly.

[This StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-leaflet-example-qbpqcj?file=Map.tsx,List.tsx,index.tsx) shows a working demo of this.